# Base64 code stays the same even though the values it is encoding are changing

Tags: javascript, html, base64

I am currently creating an incremental game much like cookie clicker. What would cookie clicker be without its save code that you can hack. I have code that takes all the values of my variables `atoms`,`clickvalue`,`elmts`,`molecules`, ect. it puts them in a string with spacers. Then it encodes it to Base64. This is where the problems start. At first the Bace64 decoded value is the same as it was when it was encoded, but if you change the values then encode and decode again the values are the same as the first time. This keeps happening no mater how many times I try it.

index.js:

```
var data = atoms + "%-%" + clickValue + "%-%" + elmts + "%-%" + molecules;
//Clicking
var atoms = 15;
var clickValue = 1;

function atomClick() {
  atoms = atoms + clickValue;
  document.getElementById("atoms").innerHTML = abbrNum(atoms , true , 2);
};

//upgrades
function upgradeClickValue () {
clickValue = clickValue * 2;
};

//Auto click modifiers
//create veriables
var elmts = 0;
var molecules = 0;

function buyElement() {
    var elementCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,elmts));
    if(atoms >= elementCost) {
        elmts++;
        atoms = atoms - elementCost;
        document.getElementById('elmts').innerHTML = abbrNum(elmts , true , 2);
        document.getElementById('atoms').innerHTML = abbrNum(atoms , true , 2);
    };
    var nextECost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,elmts));
    document.getElementById('elementCost').innerHTML = abbrNum(nextECost , true , 2);
};

function buyMolecule() {
    var moleculeCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.2,molecules));
    if(atoms >= moleculeCost) {
        molecules++;
        atoms = atoms - moleculeCost;
        document.getElementById('molecules').innerHTML = abbrNum(molecules , true , 2);
        document.getElementById('atoms').innerHTML = abbrNum(atoms , true , 2);
    };
    var nextMCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.2,molecules));
    document.getElementById('moleculeCost').innerHTML = abbrNum(nextMCost , true , 2);
};

window.setInterval(function() {

    atoms = atoms + (elmts * 1) + (molecules * 2);
    document.getElementById('atoms').innerHTML = abbrNum(atoms , true , 2);

    document.title  = "AC Home :: Atoms: " + abbrNum(atoms , true , 2);

    var data = atoms + "%-%" + clickValue + "%-%" + elmts + "%-%" + molecules;
}, 1000);

//round numbers
const COUNT_ABBRS = [ '', 'K', 'M', 'B', 'T', 'Q', 'Qi', 'Se', 'Sp', 'Ot', 'No', 'De'];

function abbrNum(count, withAbbr = false, decimals = 2) {
    const i     = 0 === count ? count : Math.floor(Math.log(count) / Math.log(1000));
    let result  = parseFloat((count / Math.pow(1000, i)).toFixed(decimals));
    if(withAbbr) {
        result += `${COUNT_ABBRS[i]}`; 
    }
    return result;
}

function reset() {
    localStorage.removeItem("save")
    atoms = 0;
    clickValue = 1;
    elmts = 0
    elementCost = 10;
    molecules = 0;
    moleculeCost = 100;
}

// base64 encoding
var Base64={_keyStr:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",encode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i,s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=Base64._utf8_encode(e);while(f<e.length){n=e.charCodeAt(f++);r=e.charCodeAt(f++);i=e.charCodeAt(f++);s=n>>2;o=(n&3)<<4|r>>4;u=(r&15)<<2|i>>6;a=i&63;if(isNaN(r)){u=a=64}else if(isNaN(i)){a=64}t=t+this._keyStr.charAt(s)+this._keyStr.charAt(o)+this._keyStr.charAt(u)+this._keyStr.charAt(a)}return t},decode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i;var s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9+/=]/g,"");while(f<e.length){s=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));o=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));u=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));a=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));n=s<<2|o>>4;r=(o&15)<<4|u>>2;i=(u&3)<<6|a;t=t+String.fromCharCode(n);if(u!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(r)}if(a!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(i)}}t=Base64._utf8_decode(t);return t},_utf8_encode:function(e){e=e.replace(/rn/g,"n");var t="";for(var n=0;n<e.length;n++){var r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r)}else if(r>127&&r<2048){t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6|192);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}else{t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>12|224);t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6&63|128);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}}return t},_utf8_decode:function(e){var t="";var n=0;var r=c1=c2=0;while(n<e.length){r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r);n++}else if(r>191&&r<224){c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&31)<<6|c2&63);n+=2}else{c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);c3=e.charCodeAt(n+2);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&15)<<12|(c2&63)<<6|c3&63);n+=3}}return t}}

//set code
var data = atoms + "%-%" + clickValue + "%-%" + elmts + "%-%" + molecules;
var encodedString = Base64.encode(data);

function save() {
    // Encode the String
    var encodedString = Base64.encode(data);
    console.log(encodedString);
    alert("Save Code: " + encodedString);
}
function load() {
    // Decode the String
    var decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedString);
    console.log(decodedString);
    var splitRst = decodedString.split("%-%");
    console.log(splitRst)
    alert("Values: " + splitRst);
}
```

index.php:

```
<?php
    include_once 'header.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

</html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
  <title>AC Home :: Atoms: 0</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="inline" id="clicker">
      <br> Atoms: <span id="atoms">0</span>
      <br>
      <input type="image" class="atom-image" src="https://theatomandperiodictable.wikispaces.com/file/view/220px-Stylised_Lithium_Atom.svg.png/297637780/220px-Stylised_Lithium_Atom.svg.png" onClick="atomClick()">
    </div>

    <div class="inline" id="upgrades">
      <h3>upgrades</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="inline" id="modifiers">
      <button onClick="buyElement()" id="BuyModifier" style="height: 50px; width: 201px;">Buy Element</button><br /> elmts: <span id="elmts">0</span>
      <br />
      Cost: <span id="elementCost">10</span>
      <br />

      <button onClick="buyMolecule()" id="BuyModifier" style="height: 50px; width: 201px;">Buy Molecule</button>
      <br />
      Molecules: <span id="molecules">0</span>
      <br />
      Cost: <span id="moleculeCost">100</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br class="clearBoth" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

<?php
    include_once 'footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: What is this gigantic one line function in `Base64` and why are you not using `atob` and `btoa`?

Comment: `atob`? `btoa`?

Comment: Well, it's true that [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa) works only on strings, but i thought that would be enough here. Anyways, can it be assumed that gigantic unreadable one liner actually produces proper base64 as intended?

Comment: yes I believe so

Comment: Looking at this again, i'd still suggest just using `btoa` and use [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) as data format. Re-inventing the wheel is often not a good idea.

Comment: I have tried using JSON but have never been successful.

Comment: sometimes the simplest answers are the best answers, thanks.

Comment: request close because of typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the `var` before `data =` in your function for `setInterval`. You are shadowing the global `data` and are writing to a local variable which ceases to exist once the function ends.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just do something like this:

```
const data = {
    atoms: atoms,
    molecules: molecules,
    elements: elmts,
    clicks: clickValue 
};
const text = JSON.stringify(data);
const base64 = btoa(text);
```

and then to decode

```
const text = atob(base64);
const data = JSON.parse(text);
consol.log(data.clicks);  // your click value here
```

Without weird joining with `%-%`.

Comment: Could you post the code with it integrated into my code. its not doing anything accept popping up errors.